# Safest place for initilization code

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

My application has a datastore entry that needs to be initialized with some default values when the app is first deployed. I have a page that lets administrators of the app edit those values later, so it's a problem if the initialization code runs again and overwrites those edits.

I initially tried putting code in `appengine_config.py`, but that's clearly not correct, as any new values for the entity were overwritten after a few page loads. I thought about putting it in `main.py`, before the call to `run_wsgi_app()`, but it's my understanding that `main.py` is run whenever App Engine creates a new instance of the application. [Warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Warmup_requests) seem to have the same problem as `appengine_config.py`.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You code in appengine_config.py should check for the values existence, and only when no value exists should it define a default. You will have this problem no matter what strategy you adopt. Ensuring what ever process intialiases default values runs at most once.  I would actually have a specific handler method that you call only once.  And it then checks to make sure it shouldn't run before taking any action; In case it is called again.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely the solution to my problem. If that was posted as an answer, I would've accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you could use appengine_config.py or an explicit handler.

If you use appengine_config.py your code should check for the values existence, and only when no value exists should it define a default.

My main concern with one only initialisation code in appengine_config.py is the check for existence of these initial values will be performed on every instance startup. If there is a lot to check that's an overhead on warm starts that you may not want.

For iany initialisation code for a new instance, you will have this problem of checking existence no matter what strategy you adopt, that is "Ensuring what ever process intialiases default values runs at most once".

Personally I would actually have a specific handler method that you call only once. And it then checks to make sure it shouldn't run before taking any action; In case it is called again

Comment: When you say "explicit handler," are you referring to warmup requests? Or something else?

Comment: I am referring to a separate handler, there is no point having a warmup request always checking to see if the default entities have been created. I normally create an explicit handler i.e. /setup  (admin required) and it checks that it has not already run.  I often don't even create the handler, but define the code, then use the remote_api to invoke the setup.  But that would depend on who the target audience is of the app and it's setup.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks.